# Why is the amount rsync sent greater than received, without compression?

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I just finished copying a lot of data with rsync:

```
rsync -avv --progress /src ./dst
```

And at the end, got this report:

```
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=116101578747

sent 116,174,399,124 bytes  received 9,812,171 bytes  8,219,320.95 bytes/sec
total size is 116,118,167,547  speedup is 1.00
```

The rsync command shouldn't have used any compression or anything, and it's a local copy, so why is the received number much lower than the amount sent?

Comment: same reason a TCP file upload sends a lot of bytes one way for only a few ACKs back in the other direction

Comment: If you're sending files why would you receive anything at all? (Don't teach me about TCP ACK/rsync metadata/etc. - I know how the stuff works, it's a logical question for the OP).

Answer (score 1):

For local transfer `rsync` uses a parent client process and a child server process which communicate using the Rsync protocol through UNIX sockets or pipes. The shown number of received bytes corresponds to that received by the client parent process.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time crunching through the [man page,](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rsync.1.en) and I think I now understand what's going on:

- I'm using `-vv`, which puts me at verbosity 2
- According to `rsync --info=help`, at verbosity 2 I should get the same thing as if I used `--info=COPY,DEL,FLIST,MISC,NAME,STATS,SYMSAFE,BACKUP,MISC2,MOUNT,NAME2,REMOVE,SKIP`
- The `STATS` info option includes a "count of all non-message bytes that rsync received by the client side from the server side" ([man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rsync.1.en#stats))

So `rsync` is sending some data around within itself - maybe to verify that the copy completed correctly or something. That makes sense to me, though I'm not sure how I winded up with a client/server setup just invoking `rsync` for a local copy.

Comment: `rsync` is inherently client-server in its implementation. It switches off a load of optimisations when both parts are running on the same machine though